# how to get the all child id in viewgroup touch listener?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-custom-view, ontouchlistener, viewgroup

how to getting the all child id from View group touch listener ?
      and 
at a time one child focus on touch down and then other child view focus to gone in view group..i already complete the scale and rotate and all operation. and also implement the touch listener but all the operation in touch so not getting the at a time one childview focus and show view in it.
i m add the view in Relative layout and the Image view create the run time..

so i am confused to getting all

Comment: Your English is very difficult to understand. If you post your code, with explanation, it is easier to help.

Comment: @Christian i want to make the application on image operation runtime so i want to make the operation scale & rotate on relativelayout together.....i am confused to make...